# effeciently manage memory and python processing

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I need to read a file that is 2.5gb big. i use the following syntx:

```
import numpy as np
limit=4269*352*288*3
mat1=np.zeros(limit, dtype='uint8')
mat1=np.fromfile("path/to/file", "uint8", limit)
```

I now need to reshape this array:

```
mat_new=np.zeros([4269, 288, 352, 3], dtype='uint8')
mat_new=np.transpose(np.reshape(mat1,[4269,3,288,352]), [0,2,3,1])
```

This takes about 35 seconds on my 4gb ram, i7 second generation system.
Any way i could make it faster. Since this is just the start of my program and more complex things to come ahead. I do not need `mat1` henceforth!

Also i am reading only half the file to start with since Python gives me 'maximum memory reached' error.

Comment: You don't need create a zero array first, you can remove `np.zeros()` lines. read data from file is slow, profile your code to determine the time spending of `np.fromfile()`.

Comment: it takes about 18 seconds to read 1.25GB of data! and 12-14 seconds to reshape!

Answer (score 1):

> it takes about 18 seconds to read 1.25GB of data

It is about 70MB/s i.e., the speed is probably limited by your disk I/O performance.

If you don't need the whole file; you could use [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html):

```
mat = np.memmap("path/to/file", shape=(4269,288,352,3))
```

To avoid memory errors, use inplace operations e.g.:

```
mat_new = mat1.transpose(0,2,3,1) # no data copying
```

Also as [@HYRY said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049878/effeciently-manage-memory-and-python-processing#comment22902573_16049878), remove unnecessary `np.zeros()`.